# Java -Creating an interface based on some code

Tags: java, interface, constructor

[image]

Hi, just wanted to see if i understood the question correctly.

(i)

```
public interface Coordinate {

    public double getDegrees();

    public double getMinutes();

    public double getSeconds();

    public String getDirection();

}
```

(ii) Could i use an Abstract class instead of the interface and use the Latitude class to extend the Abstract class. (not really sure why this is advantageous? is it because i can pick and choose the methods i want to use, instead of being forced to use the implemented methods )

(iii) `public class Latitude implements Coordinate {}`

(iv) `public class Latitude extends Coordinate{}`

Comment: Yeah, that's substantially correct.  Although, at minimum, I'd use an `Enum` for direction, not string.  And you really should be able to derive it from the degrees.  And if you're using doubles, you should only need one variable, not three...  That's really more a critique of the lesson than for you, though, because I don't really like their design.

Comment: Looks good to me. As for 2) Well, you might want Longitude in future.

Comment: Tip: Avoid using tabs in your code. They are inconsistently formatted across editors and especially web pages.

Comment: check my questions answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/8713625/1065180

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`-1` and `0` are `int` not `double`

`'S'` is a `char` not a `String`

> Could i use an Abstract class instead of the interface

Apart from a `class` and an `abstract class` you can use incantation which isn't obvious.

```
public @interface Coordinate {
    public int getDegrees();
    public int getMinutes();
    public double getSeconds();
    public char getDirection();
}

static class Location implements Coordinate {
    @Override
    public int getDegrees() {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public int getMinutes() {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public double getSeconds() {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public char getDirection() {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public Class<? extends Annotation> annotationType() {
        return Location.class;
    }
}
```

Comment: Part (ii) says to give an alternative to using an interface...

Comment: You can use a `class` or an `abstract class` or an `@interface` annotation. ;)

Answer (score 2):

(i) Double check the return types for your methods. Remember that `String`s are enclosed in double quotes (`""`). What type is enclosed in single quotes (`''`)?

(ii) Yes, this sounds like a good answer. One advantage is that you can provide default implementations in a abstract class but not in an interface. Often in Java we use both in order to get the advantages from both.